# Relation between generalized Rayleigh quotients $\frac{x^{T}A x}{x^{T} B x}$ and $\frac{x^{T} B^{-1} x}{x^{T} A^{-1} x}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Assume $A,B$ are symmetric positive definite real matrices, and $A\succcurlyeq B$.

I am curious about the relation between generalized Rayleigh quotients $\frac{x^{T} A x}{x^{T} B x}$ and $\frac{x^{T} B^{-1} x}{x^{T} A^{-1} x}$, for any vector $x$.
Currently, the only relation I can think of is that they share the same upper bound $\frac{\det(A)}{\det(B)}$.

Is there any equality or inequality between these two Rayleigh quotients?

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\l{\lambda}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}
\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\BR#1{\big(#1\big)}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$The extrema of the quotient $\fracLR{x^TAx}{x^TBx}$ are given by the eigenvalues of
$$\eqalign{
Ax_k &= \l_k Bx_k \quad\iff\quad
B^{-1}Ax_k &= \l_k x_k \\
}$$
Similarly, the extrema of the quotient $\fracLR{x^TB^{-1}x}{x^TA^{-1}x}$ are given by the eigenvalues of
$$B^{-1}x_k= \mu_k A^{-1}x_k$$
Substituting $\,x=Aw\,$ yields
$$\eqalign{
B^{-1}Aw_k &= \mu_k A^{-1}Aw_k \quad\iff\quad B^{-1}Aw_k = \mu_k w_k \\
}$$
which means that the eigenvalues/extrema of the quotients are identical $\BR{\mu_k=\l_k}$ while the corresponding eigenvectors are linearly related $\BR{x_k=Aw_k}$